# Discord.js Bot doesn't ping a user or role when mentioned

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Have this simple slash command which includes pinging/mentioning `<@!${interaction.member.id}>` but it doesn't ping the mentioned user/role at all. I did enabled **Mention @everyone, @here, and All Roles** and tried to mention different users and roles still, it's not working.

This is the code:

```js
    run: async (client, interaction, args) => {

      if(!interaction.member.permissions.has('MANAGE_CHANNELS')) {
        return interaction.followUp({content: 'You don\'t have the required permission!'}).then(msg => {
    setTimeout(() => {
  msg.delete()
}, 3000)    
  })
      }
      
        const [subcommand] = args;

  const embedevent = new MessageEmbed()

        if(subcommand === 'create'){
        
            const eventname = args[1]

            const prize = args[2]

            const sponsor = args[3]
            
            embedevent.setDescription(`__**Event**__ <a:w_right_arrow:945334672987127869> ${eventname}\n__**Prize**__ <a:w_right_arrow:945334672987127869> ${prize}\n__**Donor**__ <a:w_right_arrow:945334672987127869> ${sponsor}`)
            embedevent.setFooter(`${interaction.guild.name}`, `${interaction.guild.iconURL({ format: 'png', dynamic: true })}`)
            embedevent.setTimestamp()

        }
        
        return interaction.followUp({content: `<@!${interaction.member.id}>`, embeds: [embedevent]})    
        
    }
}
```

The command is working just fine but the only problem is the pinging/mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not into interactions, but based on my experience doing bot, you should add the code first

```
const pingmember = interaction.mentions.members.first()
```

then you can do now

```
return interaction.followUp({content: `${pingmember}`, embeds: [embedevent]})
```

or

```
const pingmember = interaction.mentions.members.first()
if(pingmember) {
  //your code here
}
```